# Best practice for defining state in function component React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have came across 2 ways of defining state in function components in React. I couldn't really figure out what the difference is.

First option:

```
export function TestComponent() {
const [state, setState]: [string, Function] = React.useState('');
}
```

Second option:

```
export function TestComponent() {
const [state, setState] = React.useState<string>('');
}
```

Both work, but what is the best option to use? I prefer using the second option, just because it is shorter.

Comment: TypeScript can infer all of those types; unless you need the state to have a type other than the first value, leave them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely sufficient:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState('');
```

Note that you don't even need the `<string>` part if you're supplying the initializer.

If it were more complex, for instance `string|null`, you might need it:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<string|null>(null);
```

...but if it's always a string, no need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so there is never a need to define the state? Even if it is interface? You can just leave it empty?

Comment: @D.Bronder - It's fine if the state type can be inferred from the argument you give `useState`, which it can in the first example above. TypeScript is very good at inferring types, including generic type parameters. In the second example above, where I've allowed for the idea that `state` might be `string` or `null`, TypeScript wouldn't be able to infer that from a literal like `''`. (It could if we were passing it something that had the type `string|null`, but that would be unusual -- though not unheard of -- with `useState`.)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, and there's also the method suggested by T.J. There's no difference between these. The only difference would be if you want to initialize a state as null, then have it change to string, in that case using

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState('')
```

isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and it workings great in react :

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState('');
```

In TypeScript React it usefull to define the types

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState<string>('');
```